# Polymer-elements not visible after creation

Tags: polymer

I had to switch to the newest version of Polymer a few days ago (from version 0.0.20131010).
So I guess the following problem is caused by the incompability between these two versions.

After the page has loaded, all the elements that are contained inside another element are set as `visibility: hidden;` when I inspect them in the browser.

The outermost elements are visible, but do not have the correct position. They don't float on right edge, as they should.

Comment: What does your code look like? There have been a lot of changes since 0.0.20131010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it wasn't a Polymer problem.

It didn't float on the right edge, because I did a rotation of this element and 
had

```
 transform-ogigin: 0 0;
```

added to its CSS. Deleting this line solved the problem.

The content didn't show, because I set all the elements inside to `hidden` on creation and the function to make one element visible wasn't called initially.

Somehow all these problems didn't occur before the version switch.